# mirrored graphics when printing in Ubuntu 9.10 + WINE

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, printing, graphics, wine

When printing under Ubuntu 9.10's default WINE installation, all graphics are mirrored and flipped upside down. Text is printed correctly. So the image:

```
AB  "Regular Text"     
CD
```

Would print out:

```
DC  "Regular Text"
BA
```

(where ABCD is a graphical image.)

Printer is a Samsung ML-2010. It prints correctly with native Ubuntu applications.

Is there any sort of configuration in WINE to change how graphics are printed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a GDI printer (okay a "Smart GDI printer") -- meaning that Samsung used the Windows graphics toolkit (GDI) as part of their driver.

I wonder if WINE is exposing a bug in that?

As a workaround, try printing to the PDF device in WINE and see if it's mirrored as well. That'll narrow it down.

Comment: The PDF output is incorrect as well (using cups-pdf). It could also be a bug with Firefox as that is the only application I can currently test the printing with.

Comment: That looks like a Firefox bug. Curious as to why you're using FF in WINE but I assume you like the better optimized build for Windows.

Comment: I have problems with mouse clicks in Flash under Ubuntu x64 (with any browser). However, I found that using Firefox 3.6 / Flash directly from Mozilla.com and Adobe has fixed the problem.